# Generating a select menu using javascript/jquery arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, for-loop

I am trying to generate an HTML select menu using a javascript array. The array keys should be used as values of options. And if the array keys are entered as numbers(as what I have done in my code) they should be accepted.

```
a([selected="No of rooms", 1="1", 2="2", 3="3", 4="4", 5="5"]);


function a(x) {
 elementString = "<select>";
 for(var i in  x) {
     elementString += '<option value="">'+i+'</option>';
 }    
elementString += "</select>";
alert(elementString);
}
```

But this code does not work. And I could not find a way to use array keys as the values 
of options. Another question I got is, if I put numbers as keys it does not work(This is a requirement).

**[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/T4h76/)**

Edit: jsfiddle link works now

Comment: your browsers error / javascript console would be a good place to start.  there are numerous syntax errors to be resolved.  In particular your array notation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is syntactically wrong and JavaScript doesn't have associative arrays, the key of array's elements is their index, however you can use an object:

```
a({selected: "No of rooms", 1: "1", 2: "2", 3: "3", 4: "4", 5: "5"});
```

But it should be noted that JavaScript object doesn't have order, ie, the generated elements may be different in each browser. If you want to keep the order you should use an array, in this case an array of objects:

```
a([{
    text: "No of rooms",
    value: "...",
    selected: true
}, {
    text: "one",
    value: "1",
    selected: false
}]);

function a(x) {
    var elementString = "<select>";
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        elementString += '<option value="' + x[i].value + '"' + (x[i].selected ? "selected='selected'" : '') + '>' + x[i].text + '</option>';
    }
    elementString += "</select>";
    // document.body.innerHTML = (elementString);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have assoc massive like `var arr={"room1" : "1", "room2" : "2"}` then you can use keys of array like new array:

```
var keys = Object.keys(arr);
var k = keys.length;

var elementString = "<select>";

for(var i=0; i<k; i++) {
   elementString += '<option value="'+keys[i]+'">'+arr[keys[i]]+'</option>';
}    
elementString += "</select>";
```

And more simple method is:

```
var arr = {"room1" : "1", "room2" : 2};

for (var i in arr) {
      elementString += '<option value="'+i+'">'+arr[i]+'</option>';
}    
elementString += "</select>";
```

Answer (score 1):

The syntax of your array is wrong.

check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/T4h76/1/)

change your array as follows

```
var arr= ["No of rooms", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5"];
```

if you want to use key- value pairs, use an array of json objects.

[more about json](http://www.json.com/)

*update: [fiddle using json](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/T4h76/2/)*

```
var arr = [{
value: '1',
data: "1"
}, {
value: '2',
data: "2"
}, {
value: '3',
data: "3"
}, {
value: '4',
data: "4"
}, {
value: '4',
data: "4"
}];

a(arr);

function a(x) {
     elementString = "<select><option value='0' selected>" + "No of rooms</option>";
     for (var i in x) {
       elementString += '<option value="' + x[i].value + '">' + x[i].data + '</option>';
     }
     elementString += "</select>";
     alert(elementString);
}
```

Comment: My question is how to use array keys with this. I need to use array keys as options' values